# Catching SecurityException from HostServices.showDocument

Tags: java, javafx

I have an application with a security controller instantiated.  I have that part working.  I was testing a security exception when calling HostServices.showDocument() and I can see the "access denied" message in the log.  I also see the exception in the log:

```
access: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1388)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:462)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExec(SecurityManager.java:572)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1096)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:451)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.HostServicesDelegate$StandaloneHostService.showDocument(HostServicesDelegate.java:146)
    at javafx.application.HostServices.showDocument(HostServices.java:115)

     ... snip ...
```

However, there is no exception in the application.  The code calls the showDocument() method and the catch block is skipped as if no exception occurred.  So, I looked at the code for openjfx and there is this tidbit in [HostServicesDeletgate.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/5b42b642cefef3129c8925f5496d161ffb0ab285/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/HostServicesDelegate.java).

```
@Override
        public void showDocument(final String uri) {
            String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
            try {
                if (osName.startsWith("Mac OS")) {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(uri));
                } else if (osName.startsWith("Windows")) {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                            "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + uri);
                } else { //assume Unix or Linux
                    String browser = null;
                    for (String b : browsers) {
                        if (browser == null && Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                                new String[]{"which", b}).getInputStream().read() != -1) {
                            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{browser = b, uri});
                        }
                    }
                    if (browser == null) {
                        throw new Exception("No web browser found");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // should not happen
                // dump stack for debug purpose
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

So they are consuming the exception in the showDocument() method (which I personally think is poor form, but there is probably a reason).

One solution that comes to mind is to check permissions before calling the showDocument() method.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: For what it is worth, this issue is in the [bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8264698)